# How to represent a list of points in R

Tags: data-structures, r

I am working with a large list of points (each point has three dimensions x,y,z).

I am pretty new with R, so I would like to know what is the best way to represent that kind of information.  As far as I know, an array allows me to represent any multidimensional data, so currently I am using:

```
> points<-array( c(1,2,0,1,3,0,2,4,0,2,5,0,2,7,0,3,8,0), dim=c(3,6) )
> points
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    2    2    2    3  -- x dim
[2,]    2    3    4    5    7    8  -- y dim
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0  -- z dim
```

The aim is to perform some computations to calculate the euclidean distance between two sets of points such as:

```
points1<-array( c(1,2,0,1,3,0,2,4,0,2,5,0,2,7,0,3,8,0), dim=c(3,6) )
points2<-array( c(2,2,0,1,4,0,2,3,0,2,4,0,2,6,0,2,8,0), dim=c(3,6) )
```

(any hint in this sense would also be highly appreciated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculating the Euclidean distance between two sets of points stored like this is easy:

```
sqrt(colSums((points1 - points2)^2))
```

Although I'd second the recommendation to store dimensions in the columns.  In that case the code becomes:

```
sqrt(rowSums((points1 - points2)^2))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the distance matrix using the function [dist](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/stats/html/dist.html). This function computes the distances between the **rows** of a data matrix, so I transposed your *points* array

```
dist(t(points),method = "euclidean")
```

Another similar function to compute the distance matrix is [Dist](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/amap/html/dist.html) from package `amap`, which provides even more distance measures : ("euclidean", "maximum", "manhattan", "canberra", "binary", "pearson", "correlation", "spearman", "kendall")

Comment: Thank you.  The distance is not between the points in an array, but the distance between the two arrays as a whole.  I plan to calculate it as the sum of distances between each pair of points, sum(dist(point_i_in_array_1, point_i_in_array_2))

Comment: In that case consider also *intercluster* metrics. Take a look here http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/clv/html/cluster_scatter.html for metrics definitions and functions that calculate them.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to see what the [**CRAN Task View for Statial Data Analysis**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html) has to offer -- there are a number of suitable packages.

Comment: Thank you, your link is broken.  Do you mean http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html ?

Comment: Quite -- thanks for the fix. I must have had something else in my copy&paste buffer...

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest working with your matrix transposed, or you'll probably end up calling the function t() more than you otherwise would.

Aside from that, this is probably the data structure you want. You could do it with a data frame of course, but I think you're better off not doing so in this situation.